# UITabBar and View Controller rotation problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a `UITabBar` with 2 bar items. The initial orientation of the device is portrait. If I rotate the device to landscape while being at `tabBarItem2` the whole thing(Status Bar, TabBar, `ViewContent2`) rotates fine, but when I press the `tabBarItem1` the `ViewContent1` is still in Portrait. It also happens if I'm in `tabBarItem1`, then rotate device to landscape and I go to `tabBarItem2`.

I'm using the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method on each view controller to move things.

I think this is happening because it is triggering the actual viewController's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method and not on both of them.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both view controllers need to have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I had it on both of them. But I solved the problem by placing the rotation code inside shouldAutoRotate method instead of willRotate method. Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, you should not place rotation code here. You should put it in either `willAutorotate...` or `didAutorotate`, but glad you got it working.